# Программа неправильно переводит бинарное число в десятичную систему

Tags: c++, математика, системы-счисления

Программа умножает не на те степени двойки, которые нужны

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long dec = 0;
    string bin;

    cout << "Enter a number in binary: ";//Ввод бинарного числа
    cin >> bin;

    //Перевод
    for (int i = 1; i <= bin.length(); i++) {
        if (bin[i] == '1') { dec += pow(2, bin.length() - i);}
    }
    cout << "\nDecimal number: " << dec << endl;//Вывод числа в 10СС

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну ведь нумерация элементов начинается с 0, а у вас?

```
for (int i = 1;
```

Ну, и сам метод оставляет желать лучшего. Хотя бы потому, что `pow` дает значение типа `double`... Вот так лично мне нравится куда больше:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bin.length(); i++)
    dec = dec*2 + (bin[i]-'0');
```

Comment: Я исправил, но ответ 2878254486, а правильный 3586610891.

Comment: Нужно перевести вот это число: 11010101110001110101011011001011

Comment: `но ответ 2878254486`  [проверим](https://ideone.com/Q8lZsO)

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: Если ответ устраивает — птичка слева от него и есть "спасибо" :)